# MATLAB: how to customize non linear X axis (for example ticks at 1,2,3,4,5,20,100,'string')

Tags: matlab, graph, axis

I'm using the MATLAB plot feature to compare two vectors. I would like my X axis to represent 1 through 7, and then 14, 21, and then a category at the end for points with undetermined X values..(I'm also not sure how to represent these numberless point (they have Y values, just no X values) I could assign a large number outside any of my X values (1000) to these points, do the 1-7,14,21,1000 and then change the 1000 label to my 'string for un-numbered points'. ??

Comment: Do you want the X-scale to be linear, or just equally spaced (=gap between 1 and 2 is the same than between 7-14 etc ...) ?

Comment: I was initially thinking linear, but how would I do equally spaced? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way to do it based on the example by The Mathworks [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94288-how-do-i-create-breaks-in-the-x-axis-range-of-values-to-plot-data-with-large-gaps-in-the-x-data-more).

The trick is to create 2 x axis with different ranges and make one of them transparent. You can then play around with its properties. I modified a bit their code but kept most of their comments because they explain well the steps.

For the demo I used `scatter` to represent the points and colored the "good" points in red and the other point (here only 1) in green. You can customize all this of course. For instance I used a value of 100 and not 1000 for the x value of the 2nd axes, but I'll let you figure out how to modify it all to change the output as you wish.

```
clear
clc
close all

%// Create axes 1 and get its position
hAxes1 = axes;
axes_position = get(hAxes1, 'Position');

%// Create axes 2 and place it at the same position than axes 1
hAxes2 = axes('Position', axes_position);

%// Your data go here.
x = [1 7 14 21 100];
y = rand(1, length(x));

%// Plot the two sections of data on different axes objects

hPlot1 = scatter(hAxes1, x(1:4), y(1:4),40,'r','filled');
hold on
hPlot2 = scatter(hAxes2, x(end), y(end),40,'g','filled');

%// Link the y axis limits and fontsize property of the axes objects

linkaxes([hAxes1 hAxes2], 'y');
linkprop([hAxes1 hAxes2], 'FontSize');

%// Set the x range limits and tick mark positions of the first axes object
set(hAxes1, 'XLim', [1 25], ...
      'XTick', [1 7 14 21])
%// Set the x range limits and tick mark positions for the second axes object.
%// Also set the background color to 'none', which makes the background
%// transparent.Add the label for the "super points".

set(hAxes2, 'Color', 'none', ...
      'YTickLabel', [], ...
      'XLim', [95 100], ...
      'XTick', 100,'XTickLabel',{'Super Points'})
```

And the output:

[image]

**EDIT**

If you wish to add a fit line, I suggest adding a 3rd axes at the same position than the other 2, make it transparent and remove its X- and Y-ticks.

i.e. Add something like this:

```
hAxes3 = axes('Position', axes_position,'Color','none','YTick',[],'XTick',[]);
```

And in the call to polyfit/polyval, in my example you want to get only the first 4 elements (i.e. the red ones).

Hence:

```
p = polyfit(x(1:4),y(1:4),1);
y_poly = polyval(p,x(1:4));
```

And then plot the line on `hAxes3`:

```
hPlot3 = plot(x(1:4),y_poly)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: thanks, this worked perfectly. Any suggestions on how to fit a best fit line to the first group of points (red points)?

Comment: I tried this but am losing my points:                                           scatter(x(1:5), y(1:5),40,'r','filled');
p = polyfit(x(1:5),y(1:5),1);
f = polyval(p,x(1:5));
hold on;
hPlot1=plot(hAxes1, x(1:5),f,'--r','linewidth',1.2);
hold on 
hPlot2 = scatter(hAxes2, x(6:8), y(6:8),40,'g','filled');
hold on

Comment: Please see my edit. Basically add an axes and plot the fit line on it.